# Dynamic form labels using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I'm making a form and I need some of the labels to change based on a value of the select:

```
<%= form_for @advert do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :category, options_for_select(lista_kategorie_select.collect { |kat| [kat[0], kat[1]] }), {}, { class: "form_field form-control", id: "kategorie" } %>
  # kat[1] = selection (in jQuery) = ['mostki, 'korby', 'ramy', etc...]  
  <%= f.label :mostki, "Mostek", id: "size1" %>      
<% end %>
```

I've tried to do that as simple as possible using jQuery, but it doesn't work:

```
jQuery ->
  text_container = $('#size1')
  $('#kategorie').change ->
    selection = $('#kategorie').val()
    if selection == 'mostki'
      text_container.text('Długość mostka')
```

What's wrong with the code? Maybe there's a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to move this line:

```
selection = $('#kategorie').val()
```

Within your handler, otherwise it is executed once on page load and the selection value does not change later on.

```
jQuery ->
  text_container = $('#size1')
  $('#kategorie').change ->
    selection = $('#kategorie').val()
    if selection == 'mostki'
      text_container.text('Długość mostka')
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it still doesn't work after fixing this error

Comment: Are your option s built correctly, i.e. do all the options has right value? What does `$('#kategorie').val()` return when typed in console?

Comment: It's returning expected values, so options seem to be built correctly.

Comment: The problem is solved, I just moved the script to another file and now it's working.